# How to bypass UAC check in an MFC app without modifying system registry ?

Tags: mfc, uac

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384691.aspx is not really helping. Visual Studio enviroment settings isn't making any difference.

Comment: I think the point is that you can't. Otherwise why have it at all?

Comment: That link is telling you how to embed a manifest in your program, not how to bypass UAC. As Paul C rightly points out, you cannot bypass UAC if it is enabled. What would be the point? If it was possible, this is precisely what all malware would do.

Answer (score 1):

[My (upvoted) answer was deleted for some reason. Here it is again.]

The answer to this question is: You cannot bypass the UAC prompt. Read the following blog posting for the many reasons why:

[FAQ: Why can’t I bypass the UAC prompt?](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-blog-archive/faq-why-can-8217-t-i-bypass-the-uac-prompt/ba-p/701510)

Quoting from that FAQ:

> The designers of Windows Vista's User Account Control expressly decided not to incorporate functionality like setuid/suid or sudo found in Unix and Unix-like OSes such as Mac OS X. I think they made the right decision.
>
> ...
>
> If it were possible to mark an application to run with silently-elevated privileges, what would become of all those apps out there with LUA bugs? Answer: they'd all be marked to silently elevate. How would future software for Windows be written? Answer: To silently elevate. Nobody would actually fix their apps, and end-user applications will continue to require and run with full administrative permissions unnecessarily.

Bill

Comment: I honestly thought you had the most important conclusion from the link already: "You cannot bypass the UAC prompt." Glad to reinstate my upvote.